# Use Effect and Firebase causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using firebase and trying to load all my data at the start of the app using this code:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState<BookType[]>([]);
const bookCollectionRef = collection(db, "books");

useEffect(() => {
  const getBooks = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(bookCollectionRef);
    const temp: BookType[] = data.docs.map((doc) => {
      const book: BookType = {
        //set properties
      };
      return book;
    });
    setBooks(temp);
  };

  getBooks();
}, [bookCollectionRef]);
```

This useEffect is getting run constantly leading me to believe that I have made an infinite loop. I don't see why this would be happening because I don't think I am updating `bookCollectionRef` inside the useEffect hook. Is there possibly a problem where firebase collection references constantly get updated? Any ideas help!

Comment: how many times do you need to run it?

Comment: @Jamal just one time

Comment: ok leave the dependency empty like this:
useEffect(() => {
  const getBooks = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(bookCollectionRef);
    const temp: BookType[] = data.docs.map((doc) => {
      const book: BookType = {
        //set properties
      };
      return book;
    });
    setBooks(temp);
  };

  getBooks();
}, [])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell it may be that `collection(db, "books")` returns a new collection reference each time the component rerenders. Any time the component renders (*triggered by parent rerendering, `props` updating, or updating the local `books` state*) the new `bookCollectionRef` reference triggers the `useEffect` hook callback and updates the `books` state, thus triggering a rerender. Rinse and repeat.

If you don't need to reference the collection outside of the `useEffect` hook then simply omit `bookCollectionRef` and reference the collection directly. Trigger the `useEffect` only when the `db` value updates.

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState<BookType[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getBooks = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(collection(db, "books"));
    const temp: BookType[] = data.docs.map((doc) => {
      const book: BookType = {
        //set properties
      };
      return book;
    });
    setBooks(temp);
  };

  getBooks();
}, [db]);
```

If you only need to run the effect once when the component mounts then remove all dependencies, i.e. use an empty dependency array.